# How to view messages from moderators on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I need to view my recent received messages from moderators. From where can I view those messages?

Comment: _"Messages"_? Is there even such a thing on SO?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, moderators can send messages to users.

Comment: @Cerbrus but if you get one, it is not a good thing.

Comment: Oh, I'm such a good citizen, I figure that's why I didn't know this exists ;-) Makes sense though.

Comment: They will be in your spam folder:)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Moderator messages show up in your inbox, and are also emailed to the registered email address in your account.

You can look through your [global inbox on your network account](https://stackexchange.com/users/3803697/tarzanbappa?tab=inbox); the *inbox* tab there is only visible to you, and includes all your inbox messages, including moderator messages:

> [image: moderator messsage example]

Comment: did you send asker a mod message to demonstrate how it feels like?

Comment: I long for the day when inbox is an actual page I can go to.

Comment: @TylerH Isn't that what http://stackexchange.com/users/3273747/TylerH?tab=inbox is?

Comment: @KevinB I meant more of a dedicated page, and per site.

Comment: @TylerH you mean like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/0/name?tab=responses

Comment: @hildred No, see my previous comment.

Comment: @TylerH, that one is per site.

Comment: @hildred Yes, but it is not a dedicated page.

Comment: @TylerH [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ajax/users/tab/0?tab=responses&sort=all&page=1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ajax/users/tab/0?tab=responses&sort=all&page=1) :P

Comment: @JeremyBanks Cool :-) Now add the top bar and in-line response capabilities and you'll have me sold!