# How often do people who get private messages from moderators actually notice and read them?

Tags: support, moderation, notifications

According to [How to view messages from moderators on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298890/how-to-view-messages-from-moderators-on-stack-overflow), mod messages only show up in the receiving user's inbox at the top-left of the screen. But I've observed a couple of colleagues who are light users of Stack Exchange and have never noticed that the inbox exists until I've looked over their shoulders and pointed out to them that they have unread notifications. Assuming that this is fairly normal, and further assuming that most people who get messaged by mods are fairly new users, this makes me suspect that lots of them never even notice that they've received mod messages.

Does the site have any stats to confirm or disconfirm this suspicion? If I'm right, then it's probably worth changing the UI to thrust mod messages more overtly into recipients' faces. (Of course, it's possible that I'm wrong and the current system works fine.)

Comment: They do get emailed as well.

Comment: On the other end of the spectrum are the users who visit the messages on-site causing them to be marked as read, and fill in the reply form asking "Hi Moderator, my account has been suspended, may I know why?"

Answer (score 31):

Mod messages *also* get emailed to the user with whatever email address was used on their profile (it's actually an option the moderator can select, but it's selected by default on all messages), and a majority of our users probably only ever view the message on-site when they want to respond to it.

Mod messages get marked as "read" if the user ever opens the message *here on the site*, but since not all users actually do that (because of the reason mentioned above), any stats we could generate about it wouldn't be completely accurate. We can't know if someone actually read the email which was sent to them.

Comment: We also can't know if the email address was valid, if the email account is ever checked, or if the message ended up in the spam-box. Heck, we've had some *moderators* who put bit-bucket accounts in their profiles and ended up missing critical emails. Given that we can know 80% of the messages sent ARE read on-site, I'd say it's safe to say "at least 80%" in answer here.

Comment: @Shog9 sounds like a good reason to change the mod messages to something that's less likely to be missed on-site.

Comment: *We can't know if someone actually read the email which was sent to them.* I think there is option to know whether they opened the email or not. I saw that in several campaign managing sites, they are showing how many campaign mails were marked as spam, opened by user etc.

Comment: @MidhunMP: Email clients try very hard not to let email authors do that, because it's obviously ripe for abuse. All you need is an embedded image that pings the author via a website with a secret token, and suddenly they're alerted that the email address is valid. It's the main reason your client defaults to not showing images in emails, but I'm sure there are other tricks equally fought against. You can request read notifications which are considered "safe" but also generally cause a user prompt. Besides which, I would consider such tactics blatantly unethical.

Comment: [Like this, @l4mpi?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vCmHp.gif) Worth noting that we *used to* announce these via a big banner across the top of the page, which was initially effective but had become much less so (under 75%) by the time it was dropped.